# Hover is running into my initial animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on this animation to run when the page first load, and you have the ability to run the animation whenever you hover over the picture.

The problem i am running into is when the page first animation runs if you hover at the same time the to p tags go crazy. What is the best solution to avoid this?

here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cdh6yjwf/

```
<div class="test">
<img class="test-book" src="http://www.ansi.okstate.edu/breeds/other/llama/llama1.jpg">
<p class="fp1">1ST SHOW</p>
<p class="fp2">2ND SHOW</p>
```

Comment: [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) or [finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/)

Comment: Update your code with fiddle

Comment: it's updated, sorry about that. Been forever since i used stackoverflow and they was makin it super difficult just to link my initial fiddle

Comment: Just use CSS transitions instead of jQuery animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using stop() and also made it so that the hover action is in a function and it only initiated after the animation is complete.

```
$(".test").hover(function () {
    $(".fp1").stop(true).css("display", "none");
    $(".test").stop(true).animate({
        width: "120px"
    }, 500);
    $(".fp2").stop(true).fadeIn(1000, function () {});
```

the updated jsfiddle shows it all here http://jsfiddle.net/cdh6yjwf/6/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a boolean flag (`animationRunning`) that gets set to `true` when the animation is running. Then, you just check the value of the flag when you hover over the image: if `animationRunning == true`, don't do anything. If `animationRunning == false`, run the animation.

Comment: This seem like it would be the perfect solution but I can't get the concept to work. Can you take a look at the updated boolean to see if it looks right.  http://jsfiddle.net/cdh6yjwf/2/